# What's the Latin or Greek for ladybug?

Tags: vocabulary, greek, animals

I'm curious whether we know the Classical Latin or Greek names of the ladybug. I can't find the word in any of the dictionaries I have access to at the moment, and googling turns up [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/6ayb55/anyone_here_knows_how_to_say_ladybugladybird_in/) where the question is raised but not answered. Obviously there is a modern scientific Latin name for the ladybug (*Coccinella*), but that doesn't seem to have been used in antiquity, as far as I can tell. Do we know what the Greeks or Romans called this beetle?

Comment: My Dutch-Latin dictionary doesn't have it either.

Comment: Not sure either, but coccinella seems to refer to κοκκινέλη, red-like.

Comment: The scientific term *coccinella* was invented by Linné in 1740 from the Latin coccinus (greek κοκκινος).

At least in French an older name for the *coccinelle* (ladybug, « bête/vache à bon Dieu ») is *escarbot*. It comes from Latin *scarabeus* and could have different meanings : scarab, leaf beetle, ladybugs… Perhaps there is something similar in Latin…

Comment: The reddit thread seems to confirm this hypothesis…

Answer (score 3):

Two obvious candidates are the general words for beetles. One is *scarabaeus* and the other is *hister*. An example of the former is in [this book](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433076036346;view=1up;seq=85) of poems, from 1841, both in Latin/Greek and with an English translation. In page 60 we read:

> ## Ladybird
>
> Ladybird, ladybird, fly away home;
>   Your house is on fire, your children will burn.

Then, the translation in page 61 says:

> ## Scarabaea
>
> Parva rubens, Scarabaea, domum cito confuge pennis;
>   Ardet enim domus haec, ardebit parvula proles.

Having said that, there is [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=-v1YAAAAcAAJ&vq=ladycow&pg=PT189#v=onepage&q&f=false) English-Latin dictionary from 1711, which in the entry for "lady cow" (another name for ladybird/bug) says:

> *scarabaeus punctatus, maculatus*

I haven't found evidence for the latter to be used elsewhere (one exception could be [here](https://archive.org/details/nomenclatorentom00herr_0/page/n155)).

*Hister* as Latin for beetle can be seen [here](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b000742998;view=1up;seq=823).

None of the above is really Classical. A corpus search for *scarabaeus* is not very fruitful.

Comment: I made an edit; please double-check my work. I think the 1711 dictionary had a typo: _punctatns_ for _punctatus._ The hexameter translation of "Fly away home" is a great find!

Comment: BTW, I was just about to post a question asking if _citŏ_ was a mistake to fit the hexameter, since normally it's _citō,_ but a quick Google search turned up this book, explaining that it's a common poetic convention: https://books.google.com/books?id=NvkVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=cito+hexameter&source=bl&ots=GF0_r5TINj&sig=cjXE3K9rvGPCByvglYLKCZCQmPg&hl=la&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig7buwgtDfAhUj8YMKHXgNBQYQ6AEwBHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=cito%20hexameter&f=false